# Can not delete an element of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a part of code in which the function `removeClass` must delete an element of array in case, if some of his elements coincides with input parameters.

But it does not work.

```js
var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

function removeClass(obj, cls) {
  var arr = obj.className.split(' ');

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    if (cls == arr[i]) delete arr[i]
  }

  obj.className = arr.join(' ');

  return obj.className;
}

console.log(removeClass(obj, 'open'));
// desired output obj.className='menu'
// actual output 'open menu'
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You haven't provided any errors, or output or anything to give us any clear indication to what your problem is.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask], read the [Tour], and especially read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: arr.length, NOT arr.Length...

Comment: Are you trying to be able to remove values from the `className` of a DOM element? If so there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Why all this code for [obj.classList.remove(cls)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: its `arr.length` not `arr.Length`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help! 
Oh... it's jut automistake in with "Length" in "arr.Length". This is a part of code for personal specific project. I must use only such sintaxis. 
P.S. Sorry for my not so clear describe. it's my first question on SoF. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` method for this.

```
var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

function removeClass(obj, cls) {
  var arr = obj.className.split(' ');

  obj.className = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return cls !== item;
  }).join(' ')

  return obj.className;
}

console.log(removeClass(obj, 'open'));
```

In your code, you have used `arr.Length`. Actual syntax is `arr.length`. But even if you use fix your code then, it will not delete the item instead put `undefined` on its place, then you have to handle extra white spaces. That's why I think above solution is good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
    var obj = {
      className: 'open menu dogs cats'
    };

    function removeClass(obj, cls) {
      return (obj.className = obj.className.split(' ').filter(item => cls !== item).join(' '));
    }

    console.log(removeClass(obj, 'open'));
    console.log(removeClass(obj, 'dogs'));
```

But if you are trying to do this to a DOM element then use `classList` instead.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("mine");

console.log(el.className);
el.classList.remove('open');
console.log(el.className);
el.classList.remove('dogs');
console.log(el.className);
```

```html
<div id="mine" class="menu open dogs cats"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't replace the string?

```js
var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

function removeClass(obj, cls) {
  return obj.className = obj.className.replace(cls, '').trim()
}

console.log(removeClass(obj, 'open')); // obj.className='menu'
```

Also while working with DOM there are already methods for dooing this

```js
const b = document.querySelector('button')
b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  b.classList.remove('blue')
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.blue {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<button class="red blue">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can even make this really short

```
function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
    return element.className.split(' ')
                  .filter(class => class !== classToRemove)
                  .join(' ');
}
```

If you want to modify the element itself, just reassign the return value to `element.className`